# Aligning Multiple Objects in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad, alignment

I want to georefrence streets in Autocad.
I used _Align command for a single object, but it is not working with multiple objects.
How can we align multiple objects together in autocad?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To align any number of objects, you can transform them into a block (see [tutorial if necessary](http://www.2learncad.com/tutorials/cad-block.html)):

[image]

- launch the _bloc command
- give a random name (2)
- click on a place near the objects to be georeferenced (6)
- Select all your objects you need (4+3)
- Click on allow exploding (8)
- Click OK (9)

Next your can georeference your bloc with _align. when you're satisfied, just explode the bloc.

You can also use _wbloc to create another drawing with your streets, then use the insert external reference and georeference this external drawing. Then as final, bind the objects to your reference drawing ([see tutorial here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-5BF89799-D496-4AAD-8773-9D4BF9B9E8CD-htm.html))